# UPDATE with JOIN updates destination column only once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to replace multiple substrings in a nvarchar(max) column. The list of substrings and corresponding replacement values is in a separate table. When I run `UPDATE` statement with `JOIN`, and if I have more than one substring to replace per row in the destination table, then the replacement happens only once.

Below is the sample code that illustrates the issue, please note that for `id=1` and `rev=1` I have two values to replace in the destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.replacements
  (
     id          INT NOT NULL,
     rev         INT NOT NULL,
     target      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     replacement NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  )
go

INSERT INTO dbo.replacements VALUES (1, 1, 'abc', '123');
INSERT INTO dbo.replacements VALUES (1, 1, 'xyz', '789');
INSERT INTO dbo.replacements VALUES (2, 1, 'jkf', '321');
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.destination
  (
     id          INT NOT NULL,
     rev         INT NOT NULL,
     description NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
  )
go

INSERT INTO dbo.destination VALUES (1, 1, 'These two strings abc and xyz are to be replaced');
INSERT INTO dbo.destination VALUES (2, 1, 'This text jkf is to be replaced');
go

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.replacements m
       INNER JOIN dbo.destination d ON m.id = d.id AND m.rev = d.rev

UPDATE d
SET    d.description = Replace(d.description, m.target, m.replacement)
FROM   dbo.destination d 
       INNER JOIN dbo.replacements m ON m.id = d.id AND m.rev = d.rev

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.replacements m
       INNER JOIN dbo.destination d ON m.id = d.id AND m.rev = d.rev
```

It is expected to get value `'These two strings 123 and 789 are to be replaced'` for row 1, but the actual result of the replacement is:

```
id          rev         description
----------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           1           These two strings 123 and xyz are to be replaced
1           1           These two strings 123 and xyz are to be replaced
2           1           This text 321 is to be replaced
```

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

There could be more than 2 replacement for the same row.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't spend much time on this in regards to optimization and cleanliness, but I would do nested replaces, and add another join:

```
CREATE TABLE #replacements
  (
     id          INT NOT NULL,
     rev         INT NOT NULL,
     target      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     replacement NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  )
go

INSERT INTO #replacements VALUES (1, 1, 'abc', '123');
INSERT INTO #replacements VALUES (1, 1, 'xyz', '789');
INSERT INTO #replacements VALUES (2, 1, 'jkf', '321');
go

CREATE TABLE #destination
  (
     id          INT NOT NULL,
     rev         INT NOT NULL,
     description NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
  )
go

INSERT INTO #destination VALUES (1, 1, 'These two strings abc and xyz are to be replaced');
INSERT INTO #destination VALUES (2, 1, 'This text jkf is to be replaced');
go

SELECT *
FROM   #replacements m
       INNER JOIN #destination d ON m.id = d.id AND m.rev = d.rev

UPDATE d
SET    d.description = Replace(REPLACE(d.description, m.target, m.replacement), m2.target, m2.replacement)
FROM   #replacements m
       INNER JOIN #destination d ON m.id = d.id AND m.rev = d.rev
       INNER JOIN #replacements m2 ON m2.id = d.id AND m2.id = d.rev
WHERE m.target <> m2.target

SELECT *
FROM   #replacements m
       INNER JOIN #destination d ON m.id = d.id AND m.rev = d.rev
```

Comment: What happens when there is a third value that needs to be replaced?

Comment: dfundako, appreciate your answer, but as @Sean Lange mentioned - the number of replacement can be (and often is) more than 2. I'm starting to think that cursor is the only way to go.... :(

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this. I think I can knock out some dynamic sql that will do the trick.